# Как организовать архитектуру для конвейера формул?

Tags: php, ооп, архитектура

Пишу на php некоторое приложение, которое для фирмы делает некоторый расчет.
Какие имеет сущности - **фирма**, у нее множество параметров *(param1, param2, ..., paramN)*, есть несколько **методик** подсчета определенного уровня доверия, каждая методика включает **коэффициенты**, расчитываемые по **формулам** и **таблица соответствия** для каждой формулы.

Например:
**Рога и копыта**

1. На рынке: **5 лет**
2. Сфера: *Промышленность*
3. Бух. отчет парам. 1: **150 000** (условные параметры)
4. Бух. отчет парам. 2 2: **300 000**

Методика 1. **Основная**

1. Коэф - Бух. отчет парам. 2 / Бух. отчет парам. 1 = 2
2. Таблица соответствия для коэф. 1:

Если сфера **промышленность**, то при

коэф.1 > 2 = **5 баллов**

коэф.1 = 2 = **3 балла**

коэф.1 < 2 = 1 балл.

Для иных сфера свои коэф., но мы их не рассматриваем в примере.

Один из важных аспектов - **методик подсчета уровня доверия фирме может быть сколько угодно**, у каждого свои коэффициенты и методики расчета, но на выходе мы всегда имеет некоторый суммарный балл, который нам и нужен.

Теперь к сути - почему-то мне видится, что обоснованным было бы применить ОО-модель с примерно следующей логикой организации:

Методика 1 - класс, имеющий массив коэффициентов.
Сами коэффициенты - тоже классы, внутри которых есть метод handler, запускающий расчет по формулам.
Формулы - тоже в отдельные классы.
Таблицы соответствия - тоже отдельные классы

И матрешкой одно в другое вкладывать.
Таким образом получится набор методик, внутри которых есть ряд коэффициентов, высчитываемых через формулы и таблицы соответствия этих формул набору значений.

Тут 2 ключевых вопроса и 1 общий.

1) Если делать так, как я сказал, как загружать, например, формулы в класс коэффициента? Какой придумать загрузчик в такой ситуации?

2) Как передавать формулам данные? Не в базу же данных каждая лезть будет, запросов будет тьма. Была мысль насчет формирования некоторого объекта-источника данных, как смотрите на это?

3) Не слишком заморочено? Просто хотелось бы иметь четкую стройную структуру, а не кучу друг на друге налепленных алгоритмов.

Или может предложите другую схему?

Comment: "У методик подсчета свои методики расчета" с этим не поспоришь. У вас тут всего 2 класса (а то и один). Класс методики, который содержит коэффициенты и формулу, принимающий входные данные для расчёта и выдающий результат. И класс содержащий все методики, при условии что каждый раз нужно считать по всем методикам.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял из условий задачи, структура классов может быть такой:

1. Расчетный класс в который загружается коллекция фирм и который содержит коллекцию классов методик расчета. Также этот класс реализует основной алгоритм расчета по фирмам и хранит(выводит) результаты расчета.
2. Базовый класс фирмы с наследниками, которые каждый содержит свои параметры по фирме и разные данные.
3. Базовый класс методики расчета с наследниками, которые каждый реализуют свой алгоритм расчета по нужным коэффициентам. Где и как хранить коэффициенты решает каждый наследник по своему. Также, наследник реализует нужные формулы, которые могут быть вынесены в отдельные классы, если они используются в разных наследниках.

Расчет будет состоять в наполнении класса 1 данными по фирмам 2 и запуска расчета. Для каждой фирмы создается нужный экземпляр класса 3 который производит расчет.